# The screen (MBP 14 M1) remains dim after viewing an HDR video

Tags: google-chrome, video, youtube

My screen remains dimmed after viewing an HDR video. How do I restore its full brightness?

This occurs on YouTube in Chrome. I've viewed some HDR videos using QuickTime, but a dimmed screen like I'm experiencing with YouTube in Chrome doesn't persist.

The portion of the screen aside from the HDR video, dims. I have turned off automatic adjustment of brightness in the system settings. You might be able to experience it, if you find an HDR video on YouTube in Chrome and played it.

MBP 14 M1

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it, or flag for migration. 
[Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/) - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/463216/the-screen-mbp-14-m1-remains-dim-after-viewing-an-hdr-video